# Silverlight plugin install base with version breakdown

Tags: silverlight, plugins, web-statistics

I would like to choose which versions of Silverlight plugin to target, but can't find any recent statistics on the install base, let alone the version break down.  [Statowl.com/silverlight.php](http://www.statowl.com/silverlight.php) isn't returning any data and riastats.com is down.  [Some articles](http://advertboy.wordpress.com/2012/01/09/looking-at-silverlight-adoption-statistics-for-fun/) are referencing a 76% web clients installation base around 2012 with high Silverlight version 4 usage, but that's pretty outdated information.  Does anyone have up to date information for the Silverlight plugin install base, preferably with version breakdown?

Answer (score 0):

The client is backwards compatible. I think you will find most users are running the V5 client as that is pushed out with MS updates and was released 2+ years ago. You can set the min runtime version on the html Silverlight plugin element to alert users running an older version to upgrade to a version compatible with the version your app is compiled against.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917842(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Thank you. This approach doesn't work for me.  I need statistics.